# compressing XML file

Tags: c#

HI

I have an xml file with 500KB size which i need to send it to webservice, so i want to compress this data and send it to the webservice

i have heard of some base24Encoding something...
Can anyone throw more light on this

Suppose if i use GZipStream how can i send the file to the webservice

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like below (the first part just writes some random xml for us to work with). Your web-service would ideally take a byte[] argument, and would have (if using WSE3 or MCF over basic-http) MTOM enabled, which reduces the base-64 overhead. You just post it the `byte[]` and then reverse the compression at the other end.

```
    if (File.Exists("my.xml")) File.Delete("my.xml");
    using (XmlWriter xmlFile = XmlWriter.Create("my.xml")) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        xmlFile.WriteStartElement("xml");
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            xmlFile.WriteElementString("add", rand.Next().ToString());
        }
        xmlFile.WriteEndElement();
        xmlFile.Close();
    }
    // now we have some xml!
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
        int origBytes = 0;
        using (GZipStream zip = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
        using (FileStream file = File.OpenRead("my.xml")) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
            int bytes;
            while ((bytes = file.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) {
                zip.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);
                origBytes += bytes;
            }
        }
        byte[] blob = ms.ToArray();
        string asBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(blob);
        Console.WriteLine("Original: " + origBytes);
        Console.WriteLine("Raw: " + blob.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("Base64: " + asBase64.Length);
    }
```

Alternatively, consider a different serialization format; there are dense binary protocols that are much smaller (and as a consequence don't benefit from gzip etc). For example, serializing via protobuf-net would give you a very efficient size. But this only applies to an object-model, not to arbitrary xml data.

Comment: As i am very new to Dotnet using framework 2.0... can you please suggest a best way for this
The xml is generated out of a dataset and the source of the dataset would be an excel file (read using OLEDB)

Comment: @Sathish - you decompress in a very similar way `        using (MemoryStream incoming = new MemoryStream(blob))
        using (GZipStream unzip = new GZipStream(incoming, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            // read all...
        }`

Comment: yes i compressed it and got a .gz file but how to attach this file to webserve or how to send this file to the webservice

Answer (score 0):

There are some good articles about that here:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipcomp.html

http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2000/03/22/deviant/

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this scenario would be to have your web service accept a byte[] parameter which will represent the compressed XML. The Base64 encoding will be done automatically. To improve compression ratio you could use [MTOM encoding](http://mstecharchitect.blogspot.com/2009/01/wcf-with-mtom-message-encoding.html). This will avoid the Base64 step which consists of converting your byte array to a string in order to send it over the wire and where you loose might in compression ratio.

Answer (score 0):

You have following to choose from:

1. BinaryFormatter

   ArrayList itemsToSerialize = new ArrayList();

   itemsToSerialize.Add ( "john" );
   itemsToSerialize.Add ( "smith" );

   Stream stream = new FileStream( @"MyApplicationData.dat", System.IO.FileMode.Create );
   IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
   formatter.Serialize( stream, itemsToSerialize );

   stream.Close();
2. You could use WCF netTcpBinding
3. You could use *HttpBinding for WCF service hosted on IIS and follow [this blog](http://www.traviswhidden.com/PublicBlog/tabid/358/EntryId/420/asp-net-and-wcf-compression-via-IIS.aspx) which walks you through setting up WCF gzip compression through IIS
4. You could zip response and request and then decompress it

   new StreamReader(new GZipStream(webResponse.GetResponseStream(), CompressionMode.Decompress));

Comment: BinaryFormatter is generally a very poor choice for web-services

Comment: thanks Andrejev
i would like to go for option4... can you please help me with the sample code

Comment: I was hoping you would choose 3, because I think this is the most right thing to do.

Comment: but i am using a normal webservice or a WCF

Comment: This should work for them too I suppose. You just have to ignore part where he changes WCF code and concentrate on IIS configuration